# Alternativa aos métodos obsoletos onCreateDialog() e showDialog() da Activity?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber mas o engraçado é que eu executei aqui e deu certo mesmo dizendo que está obsoleto. O que devo fazer?

```
 private Button botao;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_pick);
    botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();

    int ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, ano, mes,
                    dia);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        String data = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + " /"
                + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + " /" + String.valueOf(year);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DATA = " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == botao)
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A indicação de código obsoleto(*deprecated*) significa que o seu uso deve ser evitado porque pode não ser suportado no futuro e que, actualmente, existem formas melhores/preferíveis de o fazer. Isso não significa, necessariamente, que o código não funcione.

O método [onCreateDialog (int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int)) foi considerado obsoleto na *Api level 8* tendo sido, na altura, substituído pelo método [onCreateDialog (int id, Bundle args)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int,%20android.os.Bundle)) que, posteriormente, na *Api level 13*, também foi considerado obsoleto.

Actualmente a forma preferencialmente usada para criar *dialogs* é usar a classe [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).